# It is possible to do a single complex query on these models rather than doing multiple queries?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

With these models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
    
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='img_profiles/')
    
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post")
    text = models.CharField(max_length=260)
    data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Following(models.Model):
    follow = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="follow")
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="follower")
    
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_that_like")
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_like")
```

I would need to take data from `Post`, `User` and `Profile` for each `Post` that has `Post.user=Following.follow` where `Following.follower=request.user.id`. Added to that I nedd a `Sum` of `Like.post` for each `Post` catched.

The first part is ok with :

```
qs=Following.objects.values('follow__post__id','follow__post__text',
    'follow__post__data','follow__username','follow__first_name','follow__last_name',
    'follow__profile__img').filter(follower_id=request.user.id).order_by('-follow__post__data')
```

I would like to understand if it is possible to obtain the second part with the same query or if I need a second query / subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to understand if it is possible to obtain the second part
> with the same query

It is possible with [annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate).

You can import Count `from django.db.models import Count`
and add `.annotate(like_count=Count('follow__post__post_like'))` to your query